# Get long lifespan access/refresh token for Remember me via Keycloak Admin API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have been use Keycloak for identity solution and using its Admin REST APIs to do so.
Recently I'm looking for a way to provide remember me option for users, and tried to pass the value for remember me using Keycloak Admin APIs.

Unfortunately Keycloak's docs doesn't have any details about remember me option for access token endpoints or how to generate long lived tokens on specific condition only.

Is there anyone face similar issue and anyone have solution for this?